# How do I log out specific sessions?

Tags: command-line, bash, login, users

I have read this [these generic instructions to log users out](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-kill-and-logout-users.html), but I want more detail.

When I run the command `users` I see multiple instances of the same user. IE:
`Joe Joe Joe Joe Joe`

How do I know if Joe is active? How would I find more information about what Joe is doing in each session? (like can I close a session Joe has open, and not loose his work?)

I am familiar with the `w` command. Say this user left his terminal on at home, then came into work; but rebooting the server isn't a good idea, I just used the command

```
pkill -KILL -u Joe bash
```

This threw me out of the shell and out of the open-shell from home, with no idea if I'm loosing work in this process.

What can be done to help me evaluate which sessions can be closed safely?

I tried

```
skill -KILL -v /dev/pts/1
```

to kill a specific session, but nothing happened.

Comment: I also tried unmounting /dev/pts1 but the session remained mounted

Comment: Why do you need to kill with signal 9 (SIGKILL)? This should really only be used as the last resort! Processes won't get any time from the kernel to cleanly shut down and data loss is imminent!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using `w` to identify the idle tty, then send it SIGHUP:

`pkill -SIGHUP -t pts/5`

SIGHUP (the hangup signal) will terminate the session more gracefully, almost as if the user had issued the `logout` command herself. SIGKILL should always be a last resort.

Answer (score 1):

I must have misread a portion of your post.

There is not a good way of reconnecting to terminal session that you have lost connection to unless you are using screen or something similar. Here is a stackexchange post on launching screen on ssh connections:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48002/problems-with-automatically-starting-screen-on-ssh-login

Edit:

This is not a solution to this problem

<s>kill -9 $(ps  aux | grep "[ ]$(who | grep 'Joe' | awk '{print $2}')" | awk '{print $2}')</s>

Comment: Could you explain what it does exactly?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your post. Updated my response